# Microsoft Edge allow-insecure-localhost flag removed in Version 88.0.705.50

Tags: microsoft-edge

Last week I could navigate to `edge://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` and I could edit the flag so that my localhost could serve invalid SSL certificates. Today after the latest Edge update (Version 88.0.705.50) I can no longer find this flag.

Has it moved to another secret area? How can I allow insecure localhost SSL certs again for my application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Edge 88.0.705.50. In higher version, Edge 89.0.767.0, the flag comes back again:

[image]

I think the issue will be fixed in future version of Edge Stable. You can wait for the updates and download [Edge Dev](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download) to test your app as a workaround for now.

Comment: I'll use the dev build until the flag comes back in that case. Cheers!

Comment: this was unintentionally expired, fixed in https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2595514

Comment: I had the same issue with Chrome version 88.0.4324.96 on macOS. I installed a Canary build for the moment and it's back.

Comment: i dont see this flag any longer.

Answer (score 4):

The current stable version of Chromium `v119.0` doesn't have this flag.

It's because the expiration version for this flag is modified from `118.0` to `130.0` on Oct 4, 2023 and this change would be released in `v120.0` ([reference](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/067cdc8ab6f4c001b140055fac300d610d6cf482))

[image]

As of now, `v120.0` is scheduled to be in stable channel on `Dec 5, 2023`. ([reference](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/schedule)). It might take a bit longer if you are using microsoft edge.

[image]

Comment: Like already mentioned above, using Edge Dev also works this time.

Answer (score 4):

to workaround this issue on version 119:

- Look for the flag `Temporarily unexpire M118 flags` and enable it, the browser will ask you to restart after that.
- Then you'll see `#allow-insecure-localhost` flag appear again. Enable it and enjoy happy developer's life.

Comment: as of right now this should be the answer, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but was able to fix it with the 'WebTransport Developer Mode' flag

[image: Edge WebTransport Developer Mode]

Comment: It seems to me like this is opening a large security hole...